# How to join to the TOP 1 while performing an INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a special query from SQL Server.  It's from 2 tables:

1. Cat table which has column `catParentId`
2. Messages table which relates to `catId` column

I want to get cats by catId with last message details related to that category.  In other words, I want to get last message for each cat under the parent cat.

I created table variables and inserted values into them.  Is this the best way for performance?

The SP code:

```
USE [Lovely_umbraco_cms]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Categories_GetCatsMsgs]    Script Date: 12/30/2012 01:21:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Categories_GetCatsMsgs]
 @CatId int
AS
set @catId =1;
declare @CatMessages Table(
     RowID       INT    IDENTITY ( 1 , 1 ), 
     CatName Nvarchar(50),
     MessageCount int,
     LastMessageName nvarchar(50),
     OwnerID uniqueidentifier, 
     CreatedDate date,
     Watched int,
     commentCount int
)
--------------- @CatTable --------
declare @RowsCount int;
Set @rowscount =1;

declare @CatTable table(
    id int identity(1,1),
    catId int,
    CatName nvarchar(50),
    CatParentId int
); 
--- Insert into @CatTable
insert into @CatTable(catId,catName,CatParentId )
select catId, CatName ,CatParentId from LS_Categories WHERE(CatParentId = @CatId);
-----------------------------------

declare @CatTableID int;

declare @CatName nvarchar(50);

-------Temp Message Table --------
declare @Temp_MessagesTable table(
    [Subject] nvarchar(255),
    [Date] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [OwnerId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [WatchCount] [bigint] NULL
);
--------------- @CatMessages Varibles-----

     declare @MessageCount int;
     declare @LastMessageName nvarchar(50);
     declare @OwnerID uniqueidentifier; 
     declare @CreatedDate date;
     declare @Watched int;
     declare @commentCount int;
-------
while @rowsCount <=(SELECT count(Catid) FROM  @CatTable)
begin
    select @CatTableID = CatId, @CatName = CatName from @CatTable where id= @rowsCount;

    delete from @Temp_MessagesTable;

    insert into @Temp_MessagesTable ([Subject],[Date],[OwnerId],[WatchCount])(
    SELECT      Subject, Date, OwnerId, WatchCount
    FROM         (SELECT     TOP (1) Subject, Date, OwnerId, WatchCount
    FROM         LS_Mssages 
    WHERE     (CatId = @CatTableID) ORDER BY MsgId DESC
    ) as s 
    );
    select @LastMessageName=[Subject],@CreatedDate=[Date],
            @OwnerID=[OwnerId],@Watched= [WatchCount] from @Temp_MessagesTable

    -- insert into CatMessages Table
    insert into @CatMessages(CatName,MessageCount,LastMessageName,OwnerID,CreatedDate,Watched,commentCount)
                             (select @CatName,@MessageCount,@LastMessageName,@OwnerID,@CreatedDate,@Watched,@commentCount);
    set @rowsCount = @rowsCount+1
End

select * from @CatMessages;
```

My Tables : http://ss-projects.com/t1.jpg

Data samples: http://ss-projects.com/data.jpg

Result: http://ss-projects.com/result.jpg

Comment: Can you provide sample data and results that you want?  Often, there is a better approach than doing a loop.  Also, you should tag the question with the database you are using, which seems to be SQL Server.

Comment: I added photos, u can see it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the best way to do this in SQL.

SQL is not designed for loops, instead you want to write queries that work on all elements at once not one at a time.

The following is the same as your code code and also hi-lights the bugs (NULLS in the select list).

```
INSERT INTO CatMessages
  SELECT C.CatName, M.Subject, NULL as LastMessageName, M.OwnerID, M.Date, M.WatchCount, NULL as CommentCount
  FROM CatTable C
  JOIN LS_Mssage M ON C.CatID = M.CatID
```

The easiest way to limit the LS_Mssage table:

```
INSERT INTO CatMessages
  SELECT C.CatName, M.Subject, NULL as LastMessageName, M.OwnerID, M.Date, M.WatchCount, NULL as CommentCount
  FROM CatTable C
  JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RN
        FROM LS_Mssage) M ON C.CatID = M.CatID AND M.RN = 1
```

How this works:

First please read about how JOINS work in SQL.  It is a deep topic and any search on the web will lead you to better explanations than I can write in this short space.

The advanced technique I use is the [OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).  This over clause adds a new column to the LS_Mssage table which I call RN.  RN is an auto increasing index which restarts every time CatID changes (PARTITION BY) and is applied to a result ordered by date descending (ORDER BY [Date] DESC).  This means the newest one will always have a RN of 1.  I then join on this table only looking at rows that have an RN of 1.

To really understand this, run this query by itself:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RN
FROM LS_Mssage
```

look at and understand the new table.

This is MUCH faster than your code, this table only has to be created once, however in a loop the same amount of work needs to be done for each iteration of the loop. This is why you need to think in sets (or queries) when working with SQL.

Comment: no, i want to select cats from catTable related to parent cat
and select the last message that related to cat that was selected

Comment: maybe you mean there should be a `where C.CatPArentID = 1` at the bottom?

Comment: what about the last message only ?

Comment: @NourBerro - Ok I added the code to do that.

Comment: iwill try it and i will feed you back, thanks allot

Comment: thats amazing, would you please explain it to me, appreciated

Comment: @NourBerro - I've edited the answer with more detail.  Good Luck.